# NullPointerException when accessing items in fragment

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

Does somebody know why this is not working?

Holder comes from an adapter that has my fragment included, the rest is coming from the fragment itself.

```
@Override
public View inflateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry_list, container, true);

    mListView = (FlipView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    if (mEntriesCursorAdapter != null) {
        setListAdapter(mEntriesCursorAdapter);
    }

    mHideReadButton = (com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hide_read_button);
    mHideReadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ContentUris.withAppendedId(mUri, mEntriesCursorAdapter.getItemId(mListView.getCurrentPage()))));
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

holder.mainImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragment.onListItemClickFromFragment();
        }
    });

public void onListItemClickFromFragment(){
    LayoutInflater li = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry_list, null);
    mHideReadButton = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.hide_read_button);
    mHideReadButton.callOnClick();
}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: @Florent Anders View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry_list, container, false);

Comment: I'm accessing this method from an adapter so I don't have LayoutInflater, Container etc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by performing the fragment's action inside mHideReadButton.callOnClick() inside the Adapter.